# Bootstrap 3 : input textfield displayed on two lines

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

For my website I made a date selector based on Bootstrap 3 so a user can display different data range.

The js logic behind it works fine and I can display the expected data.

However,  I would like to insert a `<br>` in the `choosen_date` input:

```
<div class="input-group date_selector">
    <span class="input-group-addon setups_previous" id="basic-addon1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i></span>
    <input class="form-control choosen_date" 
           value="Choosen date 2018-01-01<br>second line" disabled>
    <span class="input-group-addon setups_next" id="basic-addon1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i></span>
</div>
```

... which doesn't work, the code above displays the plain html `Choosen date 2018-01-01<br>second line`

Comment: How can a single-line text input have a breaking space? Do you mean a newline?

Comment: Yes, I would like the content of the input to be displayed on two lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a textarea and add a physical newline:

```html
<textarea>I am a value
on multiple lines</textarea>
```

Be sure not to include any rogue tabs on the new line, though.

Comment: Great, much more better than what I did. With the following code, it fits perfectly to my `input-group`

`<textarea class="form-control custom-control" rows="2" style="resize:none">Text 
  on two lines</textarea>`